# Simplify Boolean Expression + (Finding whether a date is between a given date range)

Tags: java

[Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) gives a **major violation error** ("Simplify Boolean Expression") for the following code.Following returns a Boolean value of matching date method .What are the steps should I take to overcome this violation. tnx

```
private boolean matchDate(Calendar createdDate, DateDomain dateRange) {

    Calendar fromDateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDateCal.setTime(dateRange.getDateFromD());

    Calendar toDateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    toDateCal.setTime(dateRange.getDateToD());

    if (createdDate.after(fromDateCal) && createdDate.before(toDateCal)) {

        return true;

    }

    else {

        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a Sonar guru , but I would suggest you to do ,

```
   private boolean matchDate(Calendar createdDate, DateDomain dateRange) {

        Calendar fromDateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDateCal.setTime(dateRange.getDateFromD());

        Calendar toDateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        toDateCal.setTime(dateRange.getDateToD());

        return createdDate.after(fromDateCal) && createdDate.before(toDateCal);

    }
```

I hope that is what it telling.

Instead of checking the `boolean`  and returning it again a `boolean`, it's better to use that `boolean` as a return param.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `if else` and directly return the following way.

```
return createdDate.after(fromDateCal) && createdDate.before(toDateCal);
```

You `if` and `else` are redundant

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
return createdDate.after(fromDateCal) && createdDate.before(toDateCal);
```

No need redundant `boolean` values again and again using `if-else`.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a check style violation.** of sonar

SimplifyBooleanExpression

Description

Checks for overly complicated boolean expressions. Currently finds code like if (b == true), b || true, !false, etc.

Rationale: Complex boolean logic makes code hard to understand and maintain.

```
**Instead of using true false directly, just return them like above solutions.**
```